# Von Neumann universe and heriditarily countable sets

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to prove that the cardinality of $V_{\omega + 2}\cap HC$ is equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$. Here $V_{\omega + 2}$ is the Von Neumann universe at stage $\omega + 2$ and $HC = \{x\in V_{\aleph_1}\mid TC(x)\preceq\omega\}$ is the set of heriditairily closed sets.

The reason I need this is that it will help me in proving a more general statement:
$$\forall \alpha <\aleph_1[\omega<\alpha\rightarrow Card(V_{\alpha}\cap HC) = 2^{\aleph_0}] $$

So far I have proven that $V_{\omega + 1} \subseteq HC$ and that $Card(V_{\omega + 1}) = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and I have a feeling I need these two statements to prove $$Card(V_{\omega + 2}\cap HC) = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

But this is where I could not go further and I hope to get some assistance on this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ hereditarily countable sets overall, so it suffices to show that $2^{\aleph_0} \leq |V_{\omega + 2} \cap HC|$. This is trivial, since $P(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq V_{\omega + 2} \cap HC$.

To show there at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ hereditarily countable sets, define $U = \{(S, T, \prec) \mid S \subseteq T \subseteq \mathbb{N}, \prec \subseteq T^2, \prec$ is an extensional, well-founded relation on $T\}$. Clearly, $|U| = 2^{\aleph_0}$. And we can come up with a surjection $U \to HC$ defined using the Mostowski Collapse Lemma. More precisely, given $(S, T, \prec)$, let $W$ be the unique transitive set such that $(W, \in_W)$ is isomorphic to $(T, \prec)$, and let $f : T \to W$ be the unique isomorphism. Then $f(S)$ is hereditarily countable. And all hereditarily countable sets arise in this way.